# Order select using the the values of in(....) SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database

Is there any way to order the result (for example)

```
SELECT id,age, Location
FROM Student 
WHERE Location in ('NY','DC','MI','TE')
```

instead of having them as

```
id     age     Location
1       2       DC
2       2       NY
4       2       MI
6       2       TE
```

The Result should be ordered as the order of in ('NY','DC','MI','TE'):

```
id     age     Location
2       2       NY
1       2       DC
4       2       MI
6       2       TE
```

I figured that It's possible by having a temp table and inserting the  `('NY','DC','MI','TE')` into this table. Then using a left join will order it as wanted.

Is there a better solution.

Please Advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL this can be done using `FIND_IN_SET`, which gives back the index of the occurrence of the first argument in the second, the latter being a string containing comma-separated values.

I think the same thing should be possible using `CHARINDEX` - give this a try:

```
SELECT id, age, location
FROM student 
WHERE location IN ('NY','DC','MI','TE')
ORDER BY CHARINDEX (location, 'NY,DC,MI,TE')
```

Answer (score -1):

Any solution would be roughly the equivalent of using a temp table.  You could use a CTE or a subquery, but you are essentially using different syntax to perform the same operation.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't have to select city codes from a table, try some of the following:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(Location,'NY','DC','MI','TE')
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(Location,'NY,DC,MI,TE')
ORDER BY LOCATE(CONCAT(',',Location,','),',NY,DC,MI,TE,')
ORDER BY Location IN ('NY','DC','MI','TE')
```

`IN` could also accept a sub-query (`ORDER BY Location IN SELECT city_code FROM ...`)